# AIX - using egrep for pattern matching of multiple string including variables

Tags: grep, variable, aix, ps

I am trying to come up with an egrep command that can do pattern match a set of strings and variables. So far, I am using the following:

```
ps -ef <uid> | egrep "string1|string2" | egrep -v "string4|string5" | grep -v "${variable}"
```

This works, but I am trying to have a syntax that is uniform and efficient.

I could get the following command work on Linux but not on AIX:

```
ps -ef <uid> | egrep "string1|string2" | grep -v "${variable}\|string4\|string5"
```

I have gone through the man pages and tried egrep -c and such but could not make any combination work.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing grep and egrep commands together, and have dropped the required `-E` flag for grep so that it parses `|` as the alternation regular expression. Alternatively use egrep all the way through.

Use one of these:

```
ps -ef | egrep "string1|string2" | egrep -v "${variable}|string4|string5"
```

or

```
ps -ef | egrep "string1|string2" | grep -Ev "${variable}|string4|string5"
```

... being careful in either one to escape regular expression tokens in `variable` (or the various stringN's, for that matter).

See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/117549)